# getDuration() on youtube api is not a function?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I've been implementing the youtube API in my website, the `playVideo()` for example works fine, so I guess there is nothing wrong with the implementation.. but the getDuration() gets an error (not such function error)

this is how I try to do it :

```
function GetDuration() {
    var duration;
    if (ytplayer) {
        duration = ytplayer.getDuration();
    }
    $(".optionVideo").append("<p>" + duration + "</p>")
}
```

its error is that there is no such function.
could anybody know what am I doing wrong ?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V36cL/6/

Comment: Example, jsFiddle? (Because according the Youtube API the function should exist.)

Comment: Without the code as Styxxy suggests, we can't know for sure. Though looking just at this code, it could be that when this function is called, ytplayer is not fully initialized or it's the wrong object.

Comment: @thormayer: Your jsFiddle has some errors.  You forgot a `)` after `$(document).ready(`.  You forgot to include swfobject.  You didn't have jQuery selected.  Oh, and `ytplayer` is undefined.

Comment: @Rocket thanks, I've update it . http://jsfiddle.net/V36cL/3/

Comment: @thormayer: Here's a better fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V36cL/6/ :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `GetDuration` from your `onYouTubePlayerReady`, not from `$(document).ready`.  The YouTube video may be ready *after* the DOM is.

Also, your `onYouTubePlayerReady` function needs to be global (jsFiddle wraps it in an anonymous function).

```
window.onYouTubePlayerReady = function(playerId) {
    window.ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
    GetDuration();
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/V36cL/7/